# How to map one user to another (from same table)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, activeadmin

I'd like to know how to solve this problem in my model/migrations, with correct referential integrity/uniqueness constraints.

I have a user table with two types of user: support_worker and service_user (like teacher and pupil). A support_worker can provide support for many service_users. I used to have separate tables for these respective user types, but for simplicity it makes more sense to have both user types in a single 'user' table (for Devise).

I'll have another table called support_allocation which records the relationship between a support_worker and the service_user(s) they support - this support_allocation has other information stored about it (like a budget; time/money). So this table needs to map one user_id to another user_id. I imagine the table structure will look something like this: SupportAllocation (id, support_worker_id, service_user_id)

So far, my migrations look like this (I've used Devise gem to create the user table so this amends it):

```
class ChangeUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    change_table :users do |t|
      t.string :user_type # support_worker or service_user

      t.string :given_name
      t.string :family_name

      t.string :customer_reference # only for service_users
      t.date :date_of_birth # only for service_users

      t.string :job_roles # only for support_workers
  end
end

class CreateSupportAllocations < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :support_allocations do |t|
      t.boolean :active, default: true

      # This next bit is guesswork
      t.integer support_worker_id # support_worker's user_id
      t.integer service_user_id # service_user's user_id 

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Here's where I get confused... I need to create a join, but this will only do it on user_id, whereas the relationship is defined by the two user_id columns (as shown and named above). I'm not sure if this a compound key or if a single foreign key (or two) will suffice.

Here's my migration work-in-progress:

```
class AddJoins < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    change_table :support_allocations do |t|
      t.belongs_to :user, index: true
    end
  end
end
```

I'd like to know how to achieve this. For the record, I'm using ActiveAdmin for my app. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Did you take a look at Single table inheritance? It might be something that you might find useful.

Comment: Thanks; I can see how that would let me store variants of 'user' but I'm not sure how it would help me manage the relationship between the different types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need the `AddJoins` migration. Add 2 associations in your `CreateSupportAllocations` model like so:

```
belongs_to :support_worker, :foreign_key => :support_worker_id, :class_name => User
belongs_to :service_user, :foreign_key => :service_user_id, :class_name => User
```

In your activeadmin form you can set the collections for the select, for example

(in app/admin/support_allocations.rb)

```
form do |f|
  f.inputs do 
    # your inputs
    f.input :support_worker, :as => :select, :collection => User.where(:user_type => 'support_worker')
    f.input :service_user, :as => :select, :collection => User.where(:user_type => 'service_user')

  end
  f.actions 
end

# added after comments
index do
  selectable_column
  column :support_worker
  actions 
end
```

Add a to_s method in you user model like so:

```
def to_s
  "#{self.full_name}"
end
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll test this in my code later and get back to you.

Comment: Just for clarity. Please can you explain what the two lines `belongs_to :support_worker, :foreign_key => :support_worker_id, :class_name => User
belongs_to :service_user, :foreign_key => :service_user_id, :class_name => User` do?

Comment: OK. I've tried your code. The migrations work and I can import seed data. However, when I try and use ActiveAdmin I can't traverse the associations back to the user table to retrieve attributes from there. For example, this code tells me that 'user' is an undefined method: `column 'Service user', :full_name, :sortable => users.family_name do |support_allocation|
      support_allocation.user.full_name
    end`  I'm also unclear how ActiveAdmin will know which user_id (service_user_id or support_worker_id) to do the join over.

Comment: It is ActiveRecord that knows how to do the join, and that is why it is declared in the ```belongs_to``` association method in the ```User``` model. I updated the answer so you can get the index view of ```SupportAllocations``` to work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your help. I added the suggested associations to my SupportAllocation model. For the record, I also had to add the following associations to my User model to make the join work fully, in both directions:

```
  has_many :occurances_as_support_worker, :class_name => 'SupportAllocation', :foreign_key => 'support_worker_id'
  has_many :occurances_as_service_user, :class_name => 'SupportAllocation', :foreign_key => 'service_user_id'
```

I used the example [given here](http://%20%20#%20http://www.emreakkas.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-multiple-columns-to-the-same-tables-key) to work this out.

When accessing attributes specific to a type of user (i.e. using the join over support_worker_id OR service_user_id), on the index page. I use code like this:

```
 column 'Service user', :full_name, :sortable => 'service_users.family_name' do |support_allocation|
      #ServiceUser.find(support_allocation.service_user_id).full_name
      support_allocation.service_user.full_name
    end

      column 'Support worker', :full_name, :sortable => 'support_workers.family_name' do |support_allocation|
        support_allocation.support_worker.full_name
      end
```